# Python and beautifulSoup, find_all ordening

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

im trying to scrap a website, there's my code:

```
<tr class="order-by-pos" data-pos="1">
<td class="normal-td td-center td-pos">
                                        1st                                            
      <div class="race-pos-no race-pos-no-2">2</div>
 </td>
</tr>




<tr class="order-by-pos" data-pos="2">
   <td class="normal-td td-center td-pos">
                                            2nd                                           
      <div class="race-pos-no race-pos-no-1">1</div>
   </td>
</tr>
```

And my code is:

```
registros = html.find_all(class_="order-by-pos")

for entrada in registros:

    saludos = entrada.find(class_="normal-td td-runner").get_text()
    trainer = entrada.find(class_="normal-td font-12 td-trainer").get_text()

    print (saludos,trainer)
```

Soup is ordening by "race-pos-no race-pos-no-1" instead of "order-by-pos" which is the first row

Comment: can you use english?

Comment: Oh sorry, thought I was in the Spanish community

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the two bits of text from inside each row, you could use the following approach:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<tr class="order-by-pos" data-pos="1">
<td class="normal-td td-center td-pos">
                                        1st                                            
      <div class="race-pos-no race-pos-no-2">2</div>
 </td>
</tr>

<tr class="order-by-pos" data-pos="2">
   <td class="normal-td td-center td-pos">
                                            2nd                                           
      <div class="race-pos-no race-pos-no-1">1</div>
   </td>
</tr>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
registros = soup.find_all(class_="order-by-pos")

for entrada in registros:
    trainer = entrada.td.div.text
    entrada.td.div.extract()
    saludos = entrada.td.get_text(strip=True)
    print (saludos, trainer)
```

Giving you:

```
1st 2
2nd 1
```

Comment: You are welcome! Don't forget to click on the grey tick under the up / down buttons to accept the answer as the accepted solution.